# Call Function in Same Level Property in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this. I want to call `encodeToken` from inside callback in `refreshToken` property. Can any body help me how javascript work for this? Thanks.

```
var obj = {
    encodeToken: function (obj){
        var opt = {expiresInMinutes: 1}
        return jwt.sign(obj, config.jwt_key, opt);
    },

    decodeToken: function (token, callback){
        jwt.verify(token, config.jwt_key, function (err, decoded){
            callback(err, decoded);
        });
    },

    refreshToken: function (token, callback) {

        this.decodeToken(token, function (err, decoded){
            callback(err, howToCall.encodeToken());
        });
    },

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
refreshToken: function (token, callback) {
    var self = this;
    this.decodeToken(token, function (err, decoded){
        callback(err, self.encodeToken());
    });
}
```

You can read a great explanation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) - see `Simple call` and `As an object method` chapters - or [here](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/).

Answer (score 3):

```
refreshToken: function (token, callback) {
    obj.decodeToken(token, function (err, decoded) {
        callback(err, obj.encodeToken());
    });
},
```

you can refer your object with no problem.